# PSSession Access Denied Error

Tags: powershell, remote

I try connect to from the machine `psttest01` to the machine `psttest02` with PSSession and certificates as authentication. For that I used this command:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName psttest02 -CertificateThumbprint 7221fc5479300189759ed18031c9c0
```

But I get an `Access denied` Error.

When I work with Credentials like this:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName psttest02 -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

it works fine. What did I wrong? Let me know if you need some more informations

Comment: Could this apply? _Certificates are used in client certificate-based authentication. They can be mapped only to local user accounts; they do not work with domain accounts_.

Comment: I only used local accounts